# How to retrieve an array list of data in Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the Image:

[image: Here's the Image]

How do I retrieve the contents of `custProd`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear.Post some more information about your question.Probably you can get downvote

Comment: Read firebase docs and try to implement instead of asking for the whole code please.

Comment: Have you read this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I know the basic of retrieving data, but I can't get the value from a List in Firebase Database and store it on a RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Firebase ref = new Firebase(YOUR_FIREBASE_URL); 

        ArrayList custProd= new ArrayList<>();

        ref.child("customerrequest/-Ke8u4..../custProd/")
                  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                   try {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                         Map<String, String> value = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                       for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : value.entrySet())
                       {
                        String _key = entry.getKey();
                        String _value = entry.getValue();
                        // TODO add value in list
                        if (_value.length() > 0 && !custProd.contains(_value))
                                    custProd.add(_value);
                          Log.e("!__@::>", _key + " " + _value);
                         }
                  }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
      @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
              Log.e("!_@@@_@@_GetAllcustProd:>", firebaseError + "");
        }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @Rjz , not accurate but I solved my problem referring to this :)

Comment: you are welcome. this is the way to fetch and store. this is hint..just like that :)